# Centering a Javascript pop-up window

Tags: javascript

I want to center a pop-up window within a browser. However, I'd like it to work regardless of the browser size and the browsers position within the users screen.

Position within a browser is straightforward, for example (with jQuery) :

```
var left = ($(window).width()/2)-(width/2);
..
uwin = window.open(...., left=...);
```

etc. But if the users browser is not full screen, then it positions relative to full screen rather than browser.

I can get screen using

```
screen.width()
```

but that will just position on screen so that's no better.

Anyone ?

Comment: How about $(document).width() ?

Comment: Same issue as $(window). Doesn't put the pop-up relative to where the browser is on the users screen, just relative to the screen itself using the browsers width. (if that makes sense)

Comment: Completely missed that you're doing a new window here and not a in-page pop-up (which you may want to consider if at all possible), sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use both the window size and the browser position on the screen to figure out this information. You can get these from the window.screenTop and window.screenLeft properties. So, to get the the positioning you want, you would first get the position relative to the browser window:

```
var windowLeft = ($(window).width()/2)-(width/2);
```

and then you add the offset:

```
var screenLeft = windowLeft + window.screenLeft;
```

Then you can do the same for the height.